# Why is Ajax call not returning data in Mozilla?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi all I have an ajax call function which calls my api and I get data from my method every thing is working good in IE the ajax call retunrs data
but when it comes to Mozilla it goes to error call and no data is returned there and I get the following error in my browser

```
error:[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:60304/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js :: .send :: line 3"  data: no]
```

here is my ajax function I am using

```
function Loaddata(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost:19999/api/Employees/GetAllEmployees?Id=1", 
           jsonp: '$callback', 
           dataType: 'text json',
           success: function (data) { 
               if (data != null && data.length > 0) { 
                   BuildCategorieString(data) 
               } 
           },
           error: function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
               alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown); 
           }
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This document looks like it covers what you need:

http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/0x80004005_(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)_and_other_firefox_errors

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function Loaddata() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:19999/api/Employees/GetAllEmployees?Id=1",
        jsonp : '$callback',
        dataType : 'jsonp text',
        crossDomain: true,
        success : function (data) {
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                BuildCategorieString(data)
            }
        },
        error : function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I didnot get your answer whats the difference between your function and my function

Comment: dataType has jsonP (not json)

Comment: the `dataType` is different and just added `crossDomain` to the ajax setup to force jsonp on the same domain. @user2152019